# Unable to load the service index for source

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-devops

I am running into an unauthorized error on an onpremise Devops 2019 build server for a .net core 3.1 solution. It seems the build server cannot access the artifact feed although this works for other solutions. Here is the error:

```
Active code page: 65001
[command]"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" test C:\a\_work\61\s\MySolution\MySolution.csproj --logger trx --results-directory C:\a\_work\_temp
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.302\NuGet.targets(128,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://mydomin/tfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/MyFeed/nuget/v3/index.json. [C:\a\_work\61\MySolution\MySolution.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.302\NuGet.targets(128,5): error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). [C:\a\_work\61\s\MySolution\MySolution.csproj]
```

and here is the pipeline.yaml file, the error occurs in the DotNetCoreCLI@2 step:

```
# ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework)
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting the full .NET Framework.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

trigger:
- master

pool: 'Default'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '5.x'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: true
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --self-contained true  -f netcoreapp3.1 -r win10-x64 --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' 

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Any suggestions how to fix the auth problem?

I tried updating the PAT token for the artifact feed on the build server but without success.
Here is the full error message:

```
##[section]Starting: DotNetCoreCLI
==============================================================================
Task         : .NET Core
Description  : Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command
Version      : 2.153.3
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli
==============================================================================
[command]C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
Active code page: 65001
[command]"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" publish C:\a\_work\588\s\MySolution.sln --configuration Release --self-contained true -f netcoreapp3.1 -r win10-x64 --output C:\a\_work\588\a\s
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.5.0+d4cbfca49 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restore completed in 292,84 ms for C:\a\_work\588\s\MySolution\MySolution.csproj.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\NuGet.targets(124,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://MyDomain/tfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/MyFeed/nuget/v3/index.json. [C:\a\_work\588\s\MySolution.sln]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\NuGet.targets(124,5): error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). [C:\a\_work\588\s\MySolution.sln]
##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
##[error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : C:\a\_work\588\s\MySolution.sln
##[section]Finishing: DotNetCoreCLI
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to [create a PAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#create-a-pat) in DevOps, and register package feed with personal access token via the command below:

`nuget sources add -name {your feed name} -source {your feed URL} -username {anything} -password {your PAT}`

Comment: Hi @CeceDong thanks for your suggestion. I updated the the source on the build server with the command but still the build fails with the same auth error. Please see the updated error detail in the question. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Try to set system.debug to true, to see whether there is more message. Also, try to grant the build agent account `Contributor` permission in the feed.

Comment: I granted the build agent the contributor permission and set the debug flag but didn't see anything that could be related to the issue. I wonder if this is related to .net core in general. Found this https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/24013 but not sure if it is the same issue. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Have you checked `%appdata%\NuGet\nuget.config` on your build agent machine? Is there ` <packageSourceCredentials> </packageSourceCredentials>` information?

Comment: yes there is and I just updated the PAT token for the server user but still without luck, 401 unauthorized

Comment: When you publish locally, which account do you use to run the command? Could you try using the account running build agent to publish?

Comment: I am using my own account, I could try this on the build server. But I think the problem may be related to .net core 3.1. According to this https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/10399 the issue may be solved by upgrading to Devops 2020 which comes with NuGet Authenticate task

Comment: NuGet Authenticate task is the latest recommended way to authenticate to Artifacts feeds from pipelines, but it doesn't exist in Devops 2019. Please check the workaround in the following link to see whether it helps you: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/12471#issuecomment-594810802